# How to checkout a specific file in repository using sharpsvn API?

Tags: sharpsvn

How to checkout a specific or a single file in repository using SharpSvn API????

Answer (score 1):

Subversion doesn't allow checking out files by itself as the smallest working copy consists of a directory.

What you could do is the equivalent of

```
svn co http://my.example/repository/subdir --depth empty F:\scratch-dir
svn up F:\scratch-dir\file</code></pre>
```

This will give you a checkout of http://my.example/repository/subdir as F:\scratch-dir\file. This allows changing the file and committing changes to it.
(This can be accomplished in SharpSvn by `SvnClient.CheckOut()` followed by `SvnClient.Update()` with the right arguments)

Another option is

```
svn cat http://my.example/repository/subdir/file > temp-file
```

Which will give you a read only copy of the file.
(The SharpSvn equivalent of this is `SvnClient.Write()`.)

Comment: I do not see how this would be an answer to the question.