# How to get a file content or download it through SharpSVN

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I'am using SharpSvn to connect to an SVN server . I would like to get the content of a file or to copy it my disk just by using it Uri on the server. Does SharpSVN API offers this functionality. if it is, how ?
thanks.

```
example of Uri : https://svn.myproject.com/svn/Projet/file.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

See [How to checkout a specific file in repository using sharpsvn API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614627/how-to-checkout-a-specific-file-in-repository-using-sharpsvn-api)

```
Uri from = new Uri("https://svn.myproject.com/svn/Projet/file.pdf");

using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    using (var fs = File.Create(Path.GetFileName(from.LocalPath))) {
        client.Write(SvnTarget.FromUri(from), fs);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok great it works thank you. But how can i tell it where to copy the file ?

Comment: Set on the method call `File.Create(string)`. In this example that would be the [startup path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (usually be the same path of the executable). You may specify where to save the file yourself.